# Getting an Error When I Try To Output What Was Chosen From a Dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

So I have a method which I am getting a random item from a dropdown menu. I would like to output the item which was chosen so I know which option was chosen should a test fail. Here is my method:

```
    public static void DropdownSelectRandomOption(IWebElement dropDown)
    {
        dropdown. Click();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var selectElement = new SelectElement(dropDown);
        int itemCount = selectElement.Options.Count;
        var itemChosen = selectElement.SelectByIndex(rnd.Next(0, itemCount));
        Console.WriteLine($"The item chosen from the dropdown is: {itemChosen}");
        itemChosen.Click();
        dropDown.Click();
        
    }
```

I am running into an error on the line for `var itemChosen` it is saying `Cannot Assign Void to an implicitly-typed variable` what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectByIndex` [doesn't return anything](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement_SelectByIndex.htm), so there's nothing to assign to `itemChosen`.

It looks like you just want to select from [the `Options` property](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement_Options.htm):

```
var itemChosen = selectElement.Options[rnd.Next(0, itemCount)];
```

---

It's also likely (though not guaranteed, I don't have a test handy) that the console output won't contain anything useful about `itemChosen`.  You may want to output [a specific property](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement.htm) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much your solution worked like a charm. For the output I did itemChosen.Text and got what I wanted.